# Check if cell completely displayed in collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view where the cell is of the size exactly to the collectionView, so each cell should occupy the whole screen. I have implemented a functionality where the cell is snapped to the complete view whenever it's dragged or decelerated through the scroll. This is how the UX works.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1v8-WxCQUzfu8V_k9zM1UCWsf_-Zz4dpr

What I want:

As you can see from the clip, the cell snaps to the whole screen. Now, I want to execute a method after it snaps. Not before or not when it's partially displayed.

Following is the code I have written for snapping effect :

```
func scrollToMostVisibleCell(){
    let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: collectionView.contentOffset, size: collectionView.bounds.size)
    let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
    let visibleIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)!
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: visibleIndexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    print("cell is ---> ", visibleIndexPath.row)
}



func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollToMostVisibleCell()
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    scrollToMostVisibleCell()
    if !decelerate {
        scrollToMostVisibleCell()
    }
}
```

If I use `willDisplayCell` method, then it' just going to return me as soon as the cell is in the view, even if it's just peeping in the `collectionView`.

**Is there a way where I can check if the cell is completely in the view and then I can perform a function?**

I have scrapped the internet over this question, but ain't able to find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: The answer referenced by Mangesh will return all visible cells - even those that are only ***partially*** visible. Here is another answer that checks if the cell is ***fully*** visible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46833430/6257435

Comment: tried this already it just gives me an empty array. I am placing this in `scrollToMostVisibleCell()`. Should I be placing it elsewhere?

Comment: My goal is that the value should be returned as soon as the scrolling stops and the view is snapped to the collection view. (as shown in the demo video). I dont want to press a button ti get the value everytime.

Comment: Have you tried simply setting `.isPagingEnabled = true` on your collection view? It sounds like that's what you are going for...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `followedCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems()` to get visible cells `visibleIndexPaths` and check your `indexPath` is contained in `visibleIndexPaths` or not, before doing anything with cells.
Ref : @anhtu  [Check whether cell at indexPath is visible on screen UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281883/check-whether-cell-at-indexpath-is-visible-on-screen-uicollectionview)

Also from Apple : `var visibleCells: [UICollectionViewCell] { get }` . Returns an array of visible cells currently displayed by the collection view.

Comment: cell is hidden 10% but still got this cell is visible

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example of a "full screen" vertical scrolling collection view controller, with paging enabled (5 solid color cells). When the cell has "snapped into place" it will trigger `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` where you can get the index of the current cell and perform whatever actions you like.

Add a new `UICollectionViewController` to your storyboard, and assign its class to `VerticalPagingCollectionViewController`. No need to change any of the default settings for the controller in storyboard - it's all handled in the code below:

```
//
//  VerticalPagingCollectionViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 10/31/18.
//

import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class VerticalPagingCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    private var collectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        return collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    }

    private var colors: [UIColor] = [.red, .green, .blue, .yellow, .orange]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // enable paging
        self.collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true

        // set section insets and item spacing to Zero
        collectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if let cv = collectionViewLayout.collectionView {
            collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = cv.frame.size
        }
    }

    override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if let iPath = collectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems.first {
            print("DidEndDecelerating - visible cell is: ", iPath)
            // do what you want here...
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return colors.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this, but I am not looking for just basic paging! I want the user to have freedom of scrolling totally as they want it, but when they stop, the cell with most view snaps to the screen. Now after its snapped, i want the current indexpath and then perform a method. I hope that clears the doubt. This answer that you provided will just give me a cell to cell paging. I am more of looking at lets say, user scroll from cell 0 to 10. And then 10 is partially on the screen but acquires most of the view, hence it snaps to the total view.

Comment: OK - if you're still trying to iron this out, you might want to take a look at this project (not mine): https://github.com/hershalle/CollectionViewWithPaging-simplerExample ... it's doing horizontal scrolling, but should be easy enough to convert it to handle vertical scrolling (using `y` and `height` instead of `x` and `width` values).